# Marketing Cloud Interactive Email Form Doesn't Render in Outlook, Shows up Fine in Gmail

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, deliverability, interactive-email

The interactive email form block I have in an email is not showing up at all in Outlook (email is tagged with the external source, please use caution.) Even once added to safe sender list. The interactive email form shows up fine in gmail. What is the possible solution? Is it because of sfmc process of envelope and inner email blocks being from 2 different senders?

Comment: This seems to be an outlook issue, have used several outlook accounts and the interactive email form does not render at all. Are there any workarounds or is this not possible in outlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email client doesn’t support interactivity and the most common unsupported email client is Outlook.

Below are the supported email clients for the Marketing Cloud Content Builder Email Form block:

Apple iPhone
Apple iPad
Apple Mail
Gmail Webmail
Gmail App
Yahoo webmail
AOL webmail

As Outlook is not supported, I request you to check this third-party, open-source resource for more information:
https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-form/

Please refer to the following documentation for more details about the issues with the Interactive Email Form under the Display section:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_interactive_email_form_faq.htm&type=5.